# How to check authentication in synchronous handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I wrote up a handler class and I wanted to know how to validate authentication.  I also wrote up a test XML post where I included some network credientials.  What is needed to read/verify these network credientials with the Handler?

Handler:

```
public class HelloWorldHandler : IHttpHandler {
public HelloWorldHandler() {}

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){

    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;

    var stream = context.Request.InputStream; 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length]; 
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    // To enable pooling, return true here.
    // This keeps the handler in memory.
    get { return false; }
}
```

XML Post snippet:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Test", "Password");
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `HttpContext` is supposed to provide all that information. Something like:

```
context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Which should be properly set if everything is configured.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a little more help.  If in IIS I setup the authentication method to "Basic authentication", how to set it up to allow a certain userid and password.